# pytesseract image_to_string not pulling strings, but no Error

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I am using the image_to_string function in the pytesseract package to convert multiple parts of a single picture file to string.  All parts are working except for this image:

[image]

Here is the script that I am using to convert it:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

im = Image.open('image.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text)
```

Which gives the output:

> —\—\—\N—\—\—\—\—\N

I have tried breaking up the image into smaller parts as well as processing the image as a jpg and as png.  What can I do to have it output the values in the image?

Answer (score 11):

Using a different page segmentation instead of the default one seems to work.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im,config ='--psm 6'))
```

According to the tesseract wiki, option 6 assumes a single uniform block of text. I tried with other options but only this one worked.
To check for other page segmentation methods read the tesseract wiki on how to improve quality of an image.